# Conectar e desconectar Internet?

Tags: c++, windows

Gostaria de fazer dois .exe básicos, um seria para desconectar a Internet e abrir um programa e o outro seria para apenas conectar a Internet.

A parte de abrir o programa eu sei, agora desconectar e conectar a Internet em c++ ainda não aprendi. Eu sei que poderia fazer com .bat, mas na verdade é que eu sei fazer em .bat, mas queria saber em c++ também.

Em .bat o de desconectar e abrir ficaria assim:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "" DISABLED
cd diretorio
programa.exe
```

.bat para conectar simplesmente:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "" ENABLED
```

Comment: Assim você está desconectando a intrerface de rede, e não "a internet". Se a mesma interface for usada para rede local, a rede local também fica indisponível.

Comment: Eu sei, no meu caso não tem problema a rede local ser desativada ok ?

Comment: Mas se quiserem dar dois exemplos, um desconectando apenas a Internet e o outro desconectando a Internet e a rede local seria legal.

Comment: @LucasVirgili é bom prestar atenção antes de editar, pois você trocou as tags e comprometeu a pergunta. Nesse meio tempo saiu uma resposta excelente, só que baseada na linguagem errada. Daqui a algum tempo removo o comment.

Comment: Uma maneira descomplicada é usar a função `system` ou  `CreateProcess` simplesmente chamando os programas que você usa no bat, netsh, etc.

Answer (score 7):

> **Nota:** A pergunta foi editada e passaram a tag de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) para [batch](/questions/tagged/batch). Mas o propósito da pergunta é uma resposta em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Na altura desta resposta a tag era em [batch](/questions/tagged/batch), pelo que foi apresentada uma solução via [batch](/questions/tagged/batch). Vou deixar a resposta pois poderá ajudar futuros visitantes.

---

## Resposta para Batch

A maneira mais simples em Windows para desligar apenas a Internet, é proceder a removeção da *gateway* padrão.

### Desligar Internet

Segue código para recolher a informação da *gateway* e guardar a mesma num ficheiro de texto, procedendo depois à eliminação da mesma:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"

REM recolher a gateway atual
set dest=0.0.0.0
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%A in ('"route print %dest% | findstr /c:"%dest%" "') do (

REM guardar o IP e eliminar a gateway
echo %%A %%B>%dest%.txt
route delete %dest% >nul
)
exit /b
```

### Ligar Internet

Dado termos guardado a informação da *gateway* num ficheiro de texto, podemos ligar a Internet repondo a *gateway* com as definições da mesma no momento em que a removemos:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"

REM garantir que o ficheiro com as definições existe
set dest=0.0.0.0
if not exist %dest%.txt exit /b 2

REM restaurar a gateway
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (%dest%.txt) do (route add %dest% mask %%A %%B >nul)
exit /b
```

<sup>Créditos da solução para o utilizador @and31415 nesta [resposta](https://superuser.com/a/744528/94664) no SU.</sup>